# Passing an Object between PHP pages, IDE and passing object to other classes problems

Tags: php, object

I've inherited some PHP code that I need to make significant changes on.  I know with PHP it is possible to serialize an Object, and pass the serialized text between pages as FormData.  In the code I've inherited, they have done just that, But this is creating some maintainability problems.  I'm wondering if taking this approach is even a good idea.

For example ...

When the user opens **PageA.php** the following is created:

```
$expensiveObj = new ExpensiveClass($id);
```

The `$expensiveObj` is then serialized and the resulting text is stored in a div with the following:

```
<div id="expensiveObj"><?php echo strtr(base64_encode(serialize($expensiveObj)), '+/=', '-_,');?></div>
```

When **PageA.php** loads, an ajax call is made to **PageB.php**.  The content of the div is passed along as a post variable to **PageB.php**.  Within **PageB.php** the following code unserializes the  object:

```
$expensiveObj = unserialize(base64_decode(strtr($_POST['expensiveObj'], '-_,', '+/=')));
```

The fields and methods of the `$expensiveObj` are now accessible to PHP.  The problems I'm encountering are

- Because the `$expensiveObj` is not identified in **PageB.php** as an instance of the Class `ExpensiveClass` then the IDE doesn't know that the fields and functions of `ExpensiveClass` are available.  I can't do autocomplete, nor lookup within the IDE what functions are available.  Plus the IDE can't catch potential issues.  The other developer worked exclusively in VI, so he never cared.
- **PageB.php** needs to be re-factored.  There is view, business, and controller logic all happening within this page, I would prefer to create a couple of classes, but I'm encountering a problem where I don't know how to pass the `$expensiveObj` to a class.

My questions are, is there a way to pass an Object to a class? And is there a way inform the IDE that the passed in post variable is indeed an instance of `ExpensiveClass`?

Lastly, is it even a good idea to be passing around objects this way, or should I be looking at a larger re-factor?

Comment: [Sessions](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). That is all.

Comment: @Sammitch I'm not sure using sessions would solve the issues I've listed.  It's just another way of passing the data/object around in a more persistent fashion.  However if you want to expand your comment into an answer, I would certainly consider what you have to say.

Comment: +1 for sessions if possible and both pages can start the same session.

Comment: Bill probably means to just store the Object as a session variable and then it's passed from page to page without any format changing, base64 etc etc, serialisation, -- no need to worry about that and it keeps the object safe from client adjustment (because it's not serialised into the page forms etc ).

Hope that helps explain what I think the first commenter was stating (sammitch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing objects directly in HTML is never a good idea, because it can be easily changed by client. In PHP is more common to create new object on every request according to given parameters. I see you are initializing your object using `$id`, so you can just pass this id between requests. Storing data to session also isn't best practice, session should be used for session-specific data, e.g. logged-in user etc.

If the creation of the object is very expensive, you can use cache, e.g. [memcache](http://php.net/memcache), some external [library](http://www.pluf.org/doc/cache.html) or just to write your own, for example storing data in JSON on file system or in database.

Comment: I'd agree that is the better approach, but I can understand the other developer's rational behind what he did.  The problem with creating a new object is that in this particular case, is that the operation is rather expensive and time consuming. Hitting the resources multiple times is something I'd rather avoid.

Comment: I assume there is some expensive database query or something similar. In such case you can use some kind of cache, e.g. memcache or storing it as JSON to filesystem and in constructor of `ExpensiveClass` you can check whether all your data are cached or not.